# Open source version of Java Compatibility Kit

Tags: java, jvm

I remember in the past there was an infrastructure given to the public to check the compatibility of the JVM and its libraries itself. If I am correct, that was [Java Device Test Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914095332/https://jdtf.java.net/), which now has magically disappeared. In its place is only the [Java Device Test Suite](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javame-embedded/javadevice.html), which is actually only for ME edition (and commercial) or [Java Compatibility Kit](https://www.jcp.org/en/resources/tdk), which again is not open source & publicly available.

What I'd like to accomplish is to use these tests myself on other non "full JDK" JVMs, like [Avian](https://github.com/ReadyTalk/avian), [MobiVM](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm), [CrossMobile](https://github.com/crossmob/CrossMobile) or [TotalCross](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross), in order to have a rough estimation of what is missing and what to expect.

Definately I don't need to check the full JDK -- that would be out of concept. What I am more interested is more base functionality, i.e. things that one could find on the java.base (at most). So, is there any (preferably) open source toolkit available?